# More precise re-throw exception with Java SE 6 (and prior versions)

Tags: java, exception

Given the program following:

```
class FirstException extends Exception {}

class SecondException extends Exception {}

class RethrowException {
     public void rethrowMethod() throws FirstException, SecondException {
          boolean flag = true;
          try {
              if(flag)
                  throw new FirstException();
              else
                  throw new SecondException(); 
          }
          catch(Exception ex) {
              throw ex;   // does not compile "Unhandled exception type Exception" 
          }
     }
}
```

This error just happens with Java SE 6 (or prior versions) because firstly, when we build the "catch" block (catch(Exception ex)), the exception object, specified by ex, has the type of `FirstException` (or SecondException). But, when `ex` is re-thrown (`throw ex`), the Java compiler performs 3 tasks as follows:

1. Release "ex" to system.
2. Initialization new exception object, "ex" that has the type of Exception
3. Throw "ex" - that is instance of Exception, right now, not instance of `FirstException` (or `SecondException`)

Thus, in the Java SE 6, we cannot use "more precisely rethrow exception" because the reason following. However, in the Java SE 7 (or later), we can do that, because when we re-throw `ex`, the runtime system does not release and initialize new object `ex`. It will check (find) where `ex1 come from (the try block above), and so know that`ex`is an instance of`FirstException`or`SecondException`.

My explanation above is correct or not?

Comment: I can't tell what part of this is your explanation and what part is the question.

Comment: I *can* tell you that the answer to "why can I compile this on Java 7 or higher but not Java 6 or lower" (if indeed that's the case) won't have anything to do with *runtime* behavior. It'll have to do with the *compiler* having got more intelligent.

Comment: Does this really compile in Java >6? It looks like a bad practice to me.. Edit: It does, I see this example comes from the Java documentation [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html).

Comment: @NickL: Yes, it does. The compiler knows the types of the exceptions that can be thrown in the block, and knows we're rethrowing rather than throwing a new one.

Answer (score 4):

No new exception instance is created by catching the exception and throwing it from the `catch` block, in any version on Java.

In Java 6-, the *type* of the caught exception is declared as `Exception` by the `catch` block, so that is what the compiler thinks is being thrown.

In later versions, the type of the exception was inferred to be bounded to only what *could* be thrown from the `try` block.

Comment: I don't understand, when I check the type of "ex" (using instanceof), I get "FirstException". So, "ex" has the type of FirstException, why when we rethrown, the runtime system will throw Exception type, while it is FirstException?

Comment: @John `instanceof` is a *runtime* thing. The error is a *compile time* thing. The compiler is stupid. It doesn't reason out what something could be, it only looks at what it's *declared* as. Java 7+ is slightly smarter in this situation.

Comment: can I summarize this: "In Java SE 6-, the compiler does not care about everything happens before rethrowing. So, whe "ex" is rethrown, the compiler will throw Exception (it looks at what's  "ex" declared as), although, actually, "ex" is FirstException...Is it right??

Comment: @John no. The compiler does't rethrow anything; it just compiles. The runtime JVM rethrows the instance of Exception that was caught. The issue is in Java 6- the compiler works only with the type declared to be caught, ie `Exception ex` tells the compile that `ex` has a type of `Exception`, but the method is only declared to throw 2 specific subtypes on `Exception`, hence the error.

Comment: Do you have a JLS reference handy? I tried to find where this behaviour is described but haven't been able to yet.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt The documentation (where OP got the example from) describes this behaviour([link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)).  I think [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2) is the relevent JLS part "We say that a statement or expression can throw a checked exception class E if, according to the rules in §11.2.1 and §11.2.2, the execution of the statement or expression can result in an exception of class E being thrown.".

Comment: @NickL Any ideas of what changed between Java 6 and Java 7 in the JLS regarding this? See also my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58416402/1310566

Comment: @SimonForsberg, they added the whole multi-catch syntax in Java7, I believe, which meant compiler has to inspect what the `try` block actually might throw, and produce (or not) errors accordingly. If it sees that `try` only throws `IOException`, it's allowed to rethrow even the `Throwable` from the same catch block, and inferred exception type is narrowed to `IOException` regardless. This is how it behaves, to some extent.