# Catching an Exception and rethrowing it, but it's not an Exception

Tags: java, exception, throws

I stumbled upon code looking something like this:

```
void run() {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}

void doSomething() {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

This code surprises me because it looks like the `run()`-method is capable of throwing an `Exception`, since it catches `Exception` and then rethrows it, but the method is not declared to throw `Exception` and apparently doesn't need to be. This code compiles just fine (in Java 11 at least).

**My expectation** would be that I would have to declare `throws Exception` in the `run()`-method.

**Extra information**

In a similar way, if `doSomething` is declared to throw `IOException` then only `IOException` needs to be declared in the `run()`-method, even though `Exception` is caught and rethrown.

```
void run() throws IOException {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}

void doSomething() throws IOException {
    // ... whatever code you may want ...
}
```

**Question**

Java usually likes clarity, what is the reason behind this behavior? Has it always been like this? What in the Java Language Specification allows the `run()` method not need to declare `throws Exception` in the code snippets above? (If I would add it, IntelliJ warns me that `Exception` is never thrown).

Comment: *Side note: There's a bunch of questions on Stack Overflow about Java and exceptions, but I was not able to find a similar question to this one.*

Comment: Interesting. What compiler you're using? If it's IDE compiler, then check with `javac` - I've been running into cases where Eclipse compiler was more lenient.

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour on openjdk-8. Notably compiling with the `-source 1.6` flag raises a compilation error as expected. Compiling with source compatibility 7 does **not** raise the compilation error

Comment: seems like compiler is [smarter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) since Java 7 and does more checks on actual exception that could be thrown.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate and the answer can be found in the link i provided `In detail, in Java SE 7 and later, when you declare one or more exception types in a catch clause, and rethrow the exception handled by this catch block, the compiler verifies that the type of the rethrown exception meets the following conditions : 1.
1. The try block is able to throw it.
2. There are no other preceding catch blocks that can handle it.
3. It is a subtype or supertype of one of the catch clause's exception parameters.`

Comment: The [currently marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990866/more-precise-re-throw-exception-with-java-se-6-and-prior-versions) is definitely relevant, but doesn't provide a detailed enough answer IMO. There's *one* link to the JLS *in the comments to the answer* there, besides that no information.

Comment: @michalk Those links should really be in an answer and not just in a comment. If you provide a better answer to the other one (or this one if it's reopened), I will upvote it.

Comment: I guess I found a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185772/jdk-1-7-onwards-throwing-an-exception-object-from-catch-block-does-not-require) question which also is a duplicate but will answer your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rethrowing an Exception: Why does the method compile without a throws clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913834/rethrowing-an-exception-why-does-the-method-compile-without-a-throws-clause)

Answer (score 0):

I have not scan through the `JLS` as you have asked in your question, so please take this answer with a grain of salt. I wanted to make it a comment, but it would have been too big.

---

I find funny at times, how `javac` is pretty "smart" in some cases (like in your case), but leaves a lot of other things to be handled later by `JIT`. In this case, it is just that the compiler "can tell" that only a `RuntimeException` would be caught. This is obvious, it's the only thing you throw in `doSomething`. If you slightly change your code to:

```
void run() {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Exception ex2 = new Exception();
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        throw ex2;
    }
}
```

you will see a different behavior, because now `javac` can tell that there is a new `Exception` that you are throwing, un-related to the one you caught.

But things are far from ideal, you can "trick" the compiler yet again via:

```
void run() {
    try {
        doSomething();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Exception ex2 = new Exception();
        ex2 = ex;
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        throw ex2;
    }
}
```

IMO, because of `ex2 = ex;` it should not fail again, but it does.

Just in case this was compiled with `javac 13+33`

Comment: I read in some link that someone provided that if you reassign the caught exception in the catch-block, then the compiler is not able to be smart. I assume something similar applies in this case. The compiler knows that the `ex2` exception will be thrown, it was originally created as an `Exception` but is then reassigned to `ex`, and therefore the compiler is not able to be smart.

Comment: @SimonForsberg someone that has a passion for `JLS` might come and provided the needed quotes to prove this; unfortunately I don't have them.

Comment: For the record, when I change the catch block to contain a reassignment of the caught exception to itself (`ex = ex;`), the heuristic is no longer applied. This behaviour seems to be applied for all source levels from 7 through 11 and probably 13

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185772/jdk-1-7-onwards-throwing-an-exception-object-from-catch-block-does-not-require) question which is also a duplicate. This one and the dup of the possible dup explains it and also links to JLS.

Answer (score -1):

**Unchecked exceptions** do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary. RuntimeException is unchecked.

Comment: This answer provides no additional information that hasn't already been shown in my question. I already know the difference between checked unchecked exception.